# Output a List that contains a Class

Tags: c#, list, console.writeline

I have

```
list<Employee> EmployeeList = new list<Employee>();
```

I want to be able to output the objects created. I have different types of employees. In this example, I used type Class Manager. After some user input, I end that option with

```
Employee newEmployee = new Employee(name, address);
newEmployee = new Manager(name, address, salary, bonus);
EmployeeList.Add(newEmployee);
```

If i try anything with `console.writeline(EmployeeList)`
I just get the namespace.(type of class) so in this case, mynamespace.Manager

I am familiar with list but not with using Classes as the key/parameter.

edit: 
Code isnt perfect, but the overall goal is to add Employees to a list and display them in order by name.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<Employee> EmployeeList = new List<Employee>();


        bool loop = true;

        while (loop)
        {

        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Main Menu");
        Console.WriteLine("1. Add Employee");
        Console.WriteLine("2. Remove Employee");
        Console.WriteLine("3. Display Payroll");
        Console.WriteLine("4. Exit");

        Console.Write("Selection: ");



        string input = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

            switch (input)
            {
                case "1":
                case "add employee":
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine("Add Employee");
                        Console.WriteLine("1. Full Time");
                        Console.WriteLine("2. Part Time");
                        Console.WriteLine("3. Contractor");
                        Console.WriteLine("4. Salaried");
                        Console.WriteLine("5. Manager");
                        Console.WriteLine("6. Previous Menu");
                        Console.Write("Selection: ");
                        string choice = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

                        if (choice.Contains("1") || choice.Contains("full time"))
                        {
                            Console.Write("\nEmployee Name: ");
                            string name = Console.ReadLine();
                            while (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Must not be blank");
                                name = Console.ReadLine();
                            }

                            Console.Write("Employee Address: ");
                            string address = Console.ReadLine();
                            while (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(address))
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Must not be blank");
                                address = Console.ReadLine();
                            }

                            Console.Write("Employee Pay per Hour: ");
                            string pph = Console.ReadLine();
                            decimal payPerHour;

                            while (!decimal.TryParse(pph, out payPerHour))
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Must be a decimal");
                                pph = Console.ReadLine();
                            }


                            Employee newEmployee = new Employee(name, address);
                            newEmployee = new FullTime(name, address, payPerHour);
                            EmployeeList.Add(newEmployee);
```

Employee Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TrevorMolano_Project_CE07

{

class Employee : IComparable<Employee>
{


    string name;
    string address;


    public int CompareTo(Employee obj)
    {          
        Employee person = obj;

        return string.Compare(name, obj.name);


    }

    public virtual decimal CalculatePay(decimal _hpw, decimal _pph, decimal _nbb)
    {
        decimal hpw = _hpw;
        decimal pph = _pph;
        decimal answer;
        answer = hpw * pph * 52;
        return answer;

    }

    public Employee(string _name, string _address)
    {
        name = _name;
        address = _address;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Not clear what you're trying to do. Please provide a [mcve]. As an aside the first line of your code which instantiates `Employee` is entriely redundant as you re-declare it as `Manager` on the next line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah that's right since calling `Console.Writeline()` directly like that calls the default `ToString()` method which does what you have observe. What you have to do is loop through the list and display each object in it like

```
foreach(var item in EmployeeList)
{
  console.writeline(item.name +"\t"+item.address);
}
```

Moreover, your `EmployeeList` collection is of type `Employee` as seen below

```
list<Employee> EmployeeList = new list<Employee>();
```

Then the below code block is invalid unless `Manager` is of type `Employee`

```
Employee newEmployee = new Employee(name, address);
newEmployee = new Manager(name, address, salary, bonus);
EmployeeList.Add(newEmployee);
```

Comment: Ah ok i didnt understand my mistakes. Tried some tests and I think i am on the right path. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you override ToString() method in your classes you can use

```
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, EmployeeList));
```

Classes:

```
    public class Employee
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        // ...
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Employee: {0}", Name);
        }
    }

    public class Manager : Employee
    {
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Manager: {0}", Name);
        }
    }
```

If you do not want to override ToString() you can select required data with Linq:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, EmployeeList.Select(x => x.Name + " " + x.Salary)));
```